# Intercept motion event from RecyclerView in opened PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, popupwindow, motionevent

In my case I want to open `PopupWindow` by long press on `ViewHolder` item and process motion event in this window without removing finger. How can I achieve this?

I trying to open `CustomPopupWindow` by follow:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Item, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    holder.bindView(testItem)
    holder.itemView.view.setOnLongClickListener {    
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null)
        val popupMenu = CustomPopupWindow(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        popupMenu.elevation = 5f
        popupMenu.showAsDropDown(holder.itemView.view)
        true
    }
}
```

and after that disable scrolling in `RecyclerView`:

```
class CustomLayoutManager(context: Context) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {

    var scrollEnabled: Boolean = true

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return scrollEnabled
    }
}
```

Here my `CustomPopupWindow`:

```
class CustomPopupWindow(contentView: View?, width: Int, height: Int) : PopupWindow(contentView, width, height), View.OnTouchListener {

    init {
        contentView?.setOnTouchListener(this)
        setTouchInterceptor(this)
    }

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                Log.i("Touch", "Touch")
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                Log.i("Touch", "Event {${event.x}; ${event.y}}")
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP-> {
                Log.i("Touch", "Up")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

In this case `onTouch()` event never called in `CustomPopupWindow` only if I remove finger and tap again.

Thanks advance!

**SOLVED**

I solved this by adding a touch listener to the anchor view:

```
holder.itemView.view.setOnLongClickListener {    
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null)
    val popupMenu = CustomPopupWindow(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    popupMenu.elevation = 5f
    it.setOnTouchListener(popupMenu) // solution
    popupMenu.showAsDropDown(it)
    true
}
```

Thanks [@Brucelet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097224/intercept-motion-event-from-recyclerview-in-opened-popupwindow#answer-49103298)

Answer (score 0):

If you can refactor to using a `PopupMenu`, then I think [`PopupMenu.getDragToOpenListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#getDragToOpenListener()) will do what you want. Similar for [`ListPopupWindow.createDragToOpenListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html#createDragToOpenListener(android.view.View)).

You could also look at the implementation of those methods for inspiration in creating your own.

Comment: Thanks, for answer. It working fine. But I want to use custom view popup created from inflate. Is it possible in PopupMenu or ListPopupWindow?

Comment: Not easily, I don't think, but you could try looking at the implementation of those other methods and see if you can do something similar.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try it. But maybe there is some other way to solve this problem without menu?